How to properly populate a nested list and access its subelements in R
I just need to populate a nested list inside two for loops (for chain ALPHA and BETA, and for id), but I am getting a subscript out of bounds error.
This reproduces the problem:
mylist <- list()
mylist[['ALPHA']][[1]][['id1']]=46
mylist[['ALPHA']][[2]][['id1']]=28
mylist[['ALPHA']][[1]][['id2']]=87
mylist[['ALPHA']][[2]][['id2']]=12

However, if I do the following, I do not get the error, why is that?
mylist <- list()
mylist[['ALPHA']][['id1']][[1]]=46
mylist[['ALPHA']][['id1']][[2]]=28
mylist[['ALPHA']][['id2']][[1]]=87
mylist[['ALPHA']][['id2']][[2]]=12

I would rather prefer the structure above, since down the line I need the list with all ids for 1 and the list for all ids for 2.
These are easy to obtain with the structure above:
mylist1=mylist[['ALPHA']][[1]]
mylist2=mylist[['ALPHA']][[2]]

But how would I obtain such lists if the alternative structure is the only way to solve the error?
I tried this, but does not get me what I want (there is one more nested level):
sapply(mylist, "[", 2)

Any help?
Thanks!

Can you fill from the end to the start instead - mylist <- list();mylist[['ALPHA']][[2]][['id1']]=28;mylist[['ALPHA']][[1]][['id1']]=46 ? for instance?

it is possible to do that yes, but why does that work?

Note this would work if you treated 1 and 2 as a string. Like mylist[['ALPHA']][['1']][['id1']]=46. This issue that R can "autovivify" a list if you use named values, but not indexes. The problem is that if you use an index like 3, there's no way for R to know what should be at index 1 and 2. It doesn't do the extra work to make sure you are adding them in order.

You can "prebuild" your list and then fill it.
mylist <- list("ALPHA" = vector("list", 2))

> mylist
$ALPHA
$ALPHA[[1]]
NULL

$ALPHA[[2]]
NULL 

Then your code works:
> mylist[['ALPHA']][[1]][['id1']]=46
> mylist[['ALPHA']][[2]][['id1']]=28
> mylist[['ALPHA']][[1]][['id2']]=87
> mylist[['ALPHA']][[2]][['id2']]=12

> mylist

$ALPHA
$ALPHA[[1]]
$ALPHA[[1]]$id1
[1] 46

$ALPHA[[1]]$id2
[1] 87


$ALPHA[[2]]
$ALPHA[[2]]$id1
[1] 28

$ALPHA[[2]]$id2
[1] 12

As to why it works when starting from the "back"... Afaik when starting from [[2]] R is creating a list of length 2 so [[1]] has to be added at runtime. This is not the case for [[2]] when starting from [[1]], which causes the subscript out of bounds error. The second list entry needs to be added explicitly with a list() command.
